# ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -115

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, apk

eclipse android project code import in android studio after some change functionality after then build generate sign apk at that time apk not create and android studio throw "ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -115"

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your gradle.

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exact same issue with a project created in Android studio itself. I looked into my code and found that one of the xml layout files was having two fields/controls with same/duplicate id. After assigning unique id to them I am able to generate signed apk.